# How to concatenate email and OTP in graphql POST query

Tags: graphql, concatenation, cypress, web-api-testing

I have to verify OTP in graphql POST request using `cy.request()` in cypress.

I want to create a suite so it will enter a new email and get OTP from that email and after that, I want to use that email and OTP in my query so it will verify using request.

```
describe('Sign Up Test', function () {
beforeEach("Load", function () {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'event_id', 'uuid', '_cltk', 'amp_394a99_outsized.site', '_clsk', 'amp_394a99')
    cy.fixture("data").then((data) => {
        this.key = data
    })
})

it('Sign up', function () {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.xpath('//button[text()=" Sign Up with Email"]').click()
    cy.get('#email').type(email.toLocaleLowerCase())
    cy.fixture("data.json").then(profile => {
        profile.email = email
        cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/data.json", profile);
        cy.get('.ant-btn').click()
        cy.wait(2000)
    })
})

it('Check Otp', function () {
    cy.visit("https://www.mailinator.com/", { timeout: 30000 })
    cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/Data.json').then((profile) => {
        cy.get("#search").type(profile.email)
    })
    cy.xpath('//*[text()="GO"]').click()
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.contains('table tbody tr', 'OTP').click()  // find the right email
    cy.get('#html_msg_body')  // iframe
        .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')  // wait for loading
        .then(console.log)  // works with this but errors without - totally weird
        .wait(2000)
        .find("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > h2")
        .then($h2 => {
            const OTP = $h2.text()
            cy.fixture("data.json").then(profile => {
                profile.OTP = OTP
                cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/data.json", profile);
            })
        })
    cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://api.outsized.site/graphql",
        failOnStatusCode: false,
        body: {
            query: "mutation { verifyEmailOtp(email: " + this.key.email + ", otp: " + this.key.OTP + "){ message } }"
        }
    }).then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
    });
})

it.only('Sign up', function () {
    const otpQuery = `mutation { 
        verifyEmailOtp(email: "test.01@getnada.com", otp: 3262)
        { message } 
      }`
    cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://api.outsized.site/graphql",
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },            
        body: {
            query: "mutation: { verifyEmailOtp(email: " + this.key.email + ", otp: " + this.key.OTP + "){ message } }"
        },
        failOnStatusCode: false,
    }).then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.eq(200)
    });

    // Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'event_id', 'uuid', '_cltk', 'amp_394a99_outsized.site', '_clsk', 'amp_394a99')
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.xpath('//button[text()=" Sign up with email"]').click({ force: true })
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.fixture("data.json").then(profile => {
        cy.get('#email').type(profile.email)
    })
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.get('.ant-btn').click()
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.reload()
})
})
```

This is my test, first, one generates random emails using the faker library. and send OTP in that email and also save the email into my data file.
The second one gets OTP from that email and saves it to my data file.
And the third one is making a request using email and OTP.

My output:

[image: 1]

Comment: It looks like each test is dependent on the previous one(would be better to remove the tests dependency) and you have `it.only` for the last test, so maybe the data file does not contain email and OTP.

Comment: @jjhelguero, Thanks for your reply. email and OTP is present the data file